# Bitly API parameters not clear

Tags: php, url-shortener

I am trying to implement Bitly using [BitlyPHP](https://github.com/Falicon/BitlyPHP).

The Bitly API requiers several parameters in order to function and this got me confused.

Can you confirm that the tokens I use are the correct ones? - be sure they are just invented ones (but visually similar to the original ones...)

My question:

1. bitlyKey: 38136deba3e1b5d8a11adet1zd68ed9d76ee411e (Generic Access Token)
2. bitlyLogin: myBitlyUserAccount
3. bitly_clientid: **??? - not sure what I need here**
4. bitly_secret: R_34tf69f4a2aakre2kva536499645a1kf (Legacy API Key)

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
D.

Comment: You didn't just post your API secret for the world to see, did you?

Comment: Hi @MattGibson , thanks for the warning but as I wrote: "...be sure they are just invented ones (but visually similar to the original ones...)" That would have been awful - Imagine what terrorist could have done with my API secret ;-)

Comment: According to the link you posted client id is : `The client_id assigned to your OAuth app`

Comment: @Jim - yes I read that too but what would be an example of a bitly client_id? I try to look at what I got from Bitly and understand what is what and where to place everything.

Comment: @Dekers Oops! Sorry, my reading comprehension appears to be bad today.

Comment: A typical client_id looks like `Client ID: 4abcd0abc1234fa7106a7c069b2a1234567890b8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [register a new app with Bitly's OAuth tool](https://bitly.com/a/oauth_apps) they will generate a `client_id` for you.

*edit* to be clear, the process is....

1. [Register an application](https://bitly.com/a/oauth_apps)
2. [Create an OAuth app](https://bitly.com/a/create_oauth_app) and confirm the token emailed to you.
3. Fill in all the details on the form.  This will create your `client_id` and secret.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information @Terence Eden. For some reason I seem to have missed this part. But now I am even more confused :-( Is client_id what I called "Generic Access Token"? All I am interested in actually is shortening URIs via my site. I am not sure I need any app. The form asks for the "app's URL" - do I need to create an OAuth app if all I want is shortening a URL?

Comment: If *all* you want to do is shorten a link, you don't need a library. Read the Bitly documentation at http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten

Comment: OK, now I get it. The token in my case is the "Generic Access Token". Thanks a bunch!